# How to know the coordinate for Tikz drawing? Is there a way to show the coordinates in Texmaker? Thank you

Tags: coordinates

I have trouble in "estimating" the coordinates in an a0 size poster. How do I know the exact coordinate in the paper? Is there grid or ruler in Texmaker to help me? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will! From your question is is not clear what sort of coordinates you are trying to work out. It's much better to show us what you have done and say what you want to do.

Comment: Simplest method is to draw the grid in `tikz` and use that as a guide. Once you are done, just comment the "grid" portion of the code.